# Is it acceptable in a Sefer Torah or Tikkun to stretch all letters uniformly to justify the text?

Tags: jewish-books, sefer-torah, manuscripts

Given that you [aren't allowed to stretch spaces in Hebrew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43753/what-is-the-reason-for-stretched-letters-in-the-torah) (would be interested to know where the primary source for this is), is it acceptable to simply stretch *all characters in a line* by some ratio so they all increase however slightly much is necessary to justify the line? Or must only certain characters be discretely stretched in some determinate way? That is, must only the letters `הדרת` be "scaled" on there horizontal sections by a factor of 0.2 or some specific amount (e.g. 1 + 0.2, 1 + 0.4, 1 + 0.6, ...)? Or can I stretch all characters by 1.234 if it means the text is justified now?

Comment: Stretching the horizontal section of a vav is a good way to end up with a reish.

Comment: Also, you've asked several questions recently on the formatting of Hebrew text in books and Sifrei Torah - is there an XY problem here? If you're trying to do something specific involving formatting Hebrew texts, you'd probably get more useful answers if you tell us what it is. (If you're just curious how it works that's fine, of course, but it seems like you haven't gotten the answer you actually wanted, and are slightly changing your question and trying again to learn whatever you actually want.)

Comment: Hi @Rish, I want to make a replica of the Sefer Torah or Tikkun in a book format for my own personal documentation purposes. So I need to know every nitty gritty typographic detail.

Comment: @Rish I don't know Hebrew too much yet, what is reish, google leads me to resh or the beginning of the alphabet. Also, not sure why the -1's.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I do think including the motivation in the question may help you. Reish and resh are both ways one might transliterate the name of the 20th letter of the alef-bet, and a vav with the horizontal section extended looks the same as that letter, which would be problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, stretched letters were very common, although not specifically following a ratio (The *Kesset haSofer* frowns on this practice, as does the *Mishnah Berurah*, in his commentary on O"Ch 37).

Modern tikkunim follow R' Davidovitch זצ"ל, who set up a format which did not require any stretching to correctly space and fit letters, a level of achievement which is really comparable to Rashi writing his commentary on Torah or (most of) Sha"s without *Pirush Rashi* (source: my chevrutah with fellow MY user [Yitzchak](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/679/yitzchak)).

Edit: It is possible to purchase tikkunei sofrim for writing, such as [here.](https://merkazhasofrim.com/sofrus/sofrus-templates/tikun-sofrim-sefer-torah.html)

Comment: Can you link to the docs so I can find out more about that format which did not require any stretching? R' Davidovitch זצ"ל

Comment: Or if no link, can you explain the general algorithm used?

Comment: I think in the shiros you still need stretching, right?

Comment: @LancePollard, to find the system used, simply open up any tikkun korim published within the last 25+ years (Yosher, Simanim, et c.) to see this. The modern tikkunim all follow him. I could link a tikkun soferim if you'd prefer, as well, but it's a purchase link

Comment: @Heshy, no, not in the modern sifrei Torah I've seen

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Purchase link would work too, thank you!

Comment: @Heshy some people need to do so as a "chumra" for certain opinions about how the shape must be, but this seems to be a newer practice historically speaking.

Comment: BTW: A quick peek at (almost any page of) R' Davidovitch זצ"ל's tikun will show you that he _streched the truth_ - excuse the pun - when claiming this. (I used it to write my ST.)

Comment: BTW #2: It's impossible to write a kosher ST without stretching letters. Clue: Shirat haYam and Ha'azinu.