# Basic Rules for "stretching" Hebrew letters to justify the text?

Tags: text

*First tangential question, what is the stretching of letters called, is it `tikkunim`? It is hard to search for examples of this (images and books) when I don't know the terminology precisely, I have been searching "Sefer Torah text stretching" basically.*

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

[image]

Just from that image alone, it appears that words are separated by small but visible "spaces", and that letters within a word are all separated by the same smaller distance, but I'm not entirely sure what the rules are.

The main question is, what are the key rules to be aware of when stretching letters? For example, in [this CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/lancejpollard-the-decoder/pen/jOeqBvW), I found some code which has each Hebrew "glyph" in a vector format in such a way where you can stretch the 4 key letters `דהרת`. But it isn't quite right in a few respects, the x-axis layout is off for letters and spaces (I have a StackOverflow question on the code changes to make [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76020813/how-can-i-get-this-text-layout-algorithm-to-properly-scale-the-text-to-font-siz)). But the question includes these parts for formatting:

1. Should there be noticeable spaces between words in the text? Should they be a standard width which is the same between every word?
2. Do spaces between letters need to be the same everywhere, and smaller than the spaces between words?
3. Any key or supremely important rules for stretching the 4 key letters? Like maybe they should be randomly stretched, or at fixed increments, or only on certain word meanings, etc.? I assume stretching can be done arbitrarily to make it "justify" the text.

***Sidenote**: I am trying to figure out how to programmatically render any Hebrew text for a website in this "stretched/justified layout" format, and would like to do it correctly if at all possible, or close to it.*

*I have read that some scribes stretch letters at key thematic or content points in the text. That would be really great to be able to do, but I'm afraid the computer/software data behind the texts does not exist, and it would be an undertaking to implement it myself. So I am resorting to just automatically/randomly stretching letters, for the time being.*

Comment: we have much of this answered in a couple related questions https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43753/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43753/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/109559/759 Please check those out and edit this to focus on whatever details aren't covered there

Comment: I saw both of those questions and they answer different things from what I am asking here. Here I am basically asking about rules for spaces.

Comment: The basic rule is to leave the width of a single small letter between words and the width of a hair between letters. After the fact it is still kosher if a child who doesn't know the meaning (and hence doesn't use context clues) groups the letters into their words correctly and no gap is sufficiently large to form an unintended section break (generally assumed to be the width of 9 (some say 3) letters)